# Problem ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it

Tags: command-line, updates, xubuntu, services

My O.S. is ubuntu 22.04. After punching in terminal, the following message is being displayed:

```
ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: From your question. After punching in terminal, What does this mean?

Comment: Hello mfskanpur, did my answer help to solve your problem? Would be nice for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

Like you i ran into the same error message after upgrading my XUbuntu to jammy (22). So i am not used to this error, but what i found may help you. All commands must be executed as root or, recommended, using a `sudo` prefix:

- Ubuntu Advantage is a commercial thing, i.e. to pay for, see
  https://ubuntu.com/blog/infographic-ubuntu-advantage-explained
- During update the packages `ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon` and
  `ubuntu-advantage-tools` were installed.

One of the installed files of the daemon package is /lib/systemd/system/ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service, the so called unit file. Trying to enable it by `systemctl enable ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service` results in the following error message:

> The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
> Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
> units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
>
> Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
>
> • A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another
> unit's   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
>
> • A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which
> has   a requirement dependency on it.
>
> • A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path,
> timer,   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
>
> • In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
> instance name specified.

What i did:

```
systemctl disable ubuntu-advantage.service
systemctl enable ubuntu-advantage.service
systemctl disable ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service (issues error message)
systemctl start ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service
```

Then

```
systemctl -a|grep ubuntu
```

shows

> ● ubuntu-advantage-cloud-id-shim.service   not-found inactive dead ubuntu-advantage-cloud-id-shim.service
>
> ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service    loaded active running
> Desktop service for Ubuntu Advantage
>
> ubuntu-advantage.service   loaded inactive dead Ubuntu Pro Background
> Auto Attach

After the next reboot the `ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service` is neither running nor loaded but can be started by `systemctl start ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service`.

Since i do not want commercial Ubuntu Advantage i did

```
systemctl disable ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon.service
```

and

```
systemctl disable ubuntu-advantage.service
```

Since you did not describe the situation the error message occurs in your terminal in detail, i cannot help you more.

More information about services and unit files you may find here:
https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/